# How to quickly generate a list of n repeating elements？

Tags: dolphindb

In Python, I can enter this:

```
["xyz"]*5
```

If I execute the same script in DolphinDB, this error is raised:

```
Arguments for mul(*) method can not be string.
```

Is there a way to quickly generate a list of n repeating elements?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Python, right? It's basically asking how to do something in DolphinDB, which has a superficially Python-like syntax, but not asking about Python at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the DolphinDB built-in function `take(X,n)`.

Generate n identical values of scalar X or take n values iteratively and sequentially from vector/matrix X. The result is a vector.

In your example, to generate a list of 5 “xyz“ strings, please use the following script:

```
take(["xyz"],5)
```

Output:

```
offset   0        1        2        3        4
-------- -------- -------- -------- -------- --------
0        xyz      xyz      xyz      xyz      xyz
```